ASP.NET MVC partial view rendering so slow
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web project on .NET 4.7.2. When I click on a dynamically generated menu in _Layout.cshtml, it navigates to the corresponding page. However, the first request sent for each groupPath (by group) results in a slow page load.
After the initial load, subsequent requests within the same group and different hrefs load quickly. Why does this happen, and how can I reduce the initial rendering time?
newTab.find('a').one('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var groupPath = group + "/" + href;
    newTabContent.html('<p>Loading...</r>');

    fetch(groupPath, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            try {
                newTabContent.html(text);
            } catch (error) {

            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Fetch error: ', error));
});

public ActionResult A01() { return PartialView(); }
public ActionResult A02() { return PartialView(); }
public ActionResult A03() { return PartialView(); }
public ActionResult A04() { return PartialView(); }
public ActionResult A05() { return PartialView(); }

enter image description here
I created a page with minimal content, as shown in the screenshot, for testing purposes. However, even when attempting the first render, it took 4 to 5 seconds. I also tried applying PreCompile during publishing, but the result was the same.

When you enabled pre-compilation did you disable the "Allow precompiled site to be updateable" option under the "Configure" options for pre-compilation?

I tried enabling it and disabling it, but the results were almost the same.
